# Deciding on a text to print based on user input

Tags: c#, console-application, user-input

this is my first programming class and I'm having a hard time with some of the concepts.

What I'm looking to do is have a box pop up that asks the user for an integer, which works.

After that, if the integer is negative it should say "enter a positive number".
Then if it's a 0, it should say "enter a non-zero number".

Lastly, it should loop four times if it's an even number,
and it should loop four times if it's an odd number.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter an integer:");
    string line = Console.ReadLine(); // Read string from console
    int value;
    if (int.TryParse(line, out value)) // Try to parse the string as an integer
    {
        Console.Write("Enter a positive number:");
        Console.WriteLine(); // Multiply the integer and display it
    }
    else if (int.TryParse(line, out value))
    {
        Console.Write("Enter a non-zero number:");
        string line1 = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine();
```

Comment: What is the problem you're having?

Comment: sounds like you need a `while` loop and a few `for` loops.

Comment: Read up on how to use TryParse

Comment: If you want to read only _one_ number there should only be _one_ `ReadLine()` statement.

Comment: If I enter an integer of 10, it'll show "enter a positive number". It should only ask that when I enter a negative integer.

Comment: you are using the same condition on both your `if` and `else if`. This means that, if the condition is true, only your `if` block will run, and if it is false, neither will run. Consider capturing the return value of TryParse (a bool that indicates if the parse was successful) and then do an `if / else if` based on that.

Answer (score 3):

Your conditional branches are a bit off. You're prompting the user to "Enter a positive number" regardless of what integer they entered. Inside your first `if` branch, you need to evaluate whether the number is positive or negative, and figure out what to do next. The `TryParse` will only be false if the entered string can't be parsed as an integer at all.

```
    if (int.TryParse(line, out value)) // Try to parse the string as an integer
    {
        // User entered a valid integer. Now check value<0 or value==0, else do your looping
    } else {
        // What user entered wasn't an integer at all. Show error.
    }
```

Note that you shouldn't actually need to read any more input from the user. All the information you need is available after the first `ReadLine`.

Comment: Thank you, that helps me. It's difficult to learn this information without any help from my professor.

Comment: @Dan What I'd suggest is going through the relevant chapter in any textbook or course notes you have. You might pick up a lot of extra information that you don't need for this assignment, but you have a much more comprehensive understanding of what's going on with your code. The other (excellent) answers here provide an explicit guide to what you need to do, although you might want to give it a shot by yourself first.

Comment: Thank you. I've tried looking through the text. The more I read through it the less helpful it's becoming for me. Microsoft Visual C# 2012 Step by Step.

Comment: @Dan Based on your comments, it seems like you're still having trouble. Have you tried making a flow chart or a detailed step by step plain english explanation of what your program is supposed to do?

Comment: Detailed steps yes. I'm not sure where else to turn. What I wrote above is what the professor said to do. I've spent hours each day for the last week trying to figure it out.

Comment: @Dan Those aren't detailed steps. There's a gap between a box popping up to prompt the user for some input and doing branching based on the sign of the integer. The user enters a string, not an integer. Pretend you're the program and ask yourself what you've been told to do at each stage. The first thing you've been asked to do is get a string from the user. What now?

Comment: Honestly, I'm so confused and lost right now. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: @Dan What are you confused and lost about? You keep repeating that you're lost and confused, but it would be more productive to explicitly state what part you don't understand.

Comment: Well, I want to ask the user for to enter a number. That part I believe is coded properly.
Next I need to have some code that would check if the integer entered is positive or negative. If it's negative, I need it to say "Please enter a positive number"
I'm lost on what to code to have it check if my integer is positive or negative.

Comment: Let's continue this [here](http://www.disposablechat.com/chat/temp?password=).

Answer (score 2):

Integers can be negative and therefore yours tests are not correct. "-12" will be parsed as expected as the integer -12. You will therefore need to test if the integer is greater than 0.

Also, as "D Standley" said you may need a loop if you want to keep asking the user to enter a positive integer. The code below sh

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int value = 0;
        while(value < 1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter a positive integer:");
            string line = Console.ReadLine(); // Read string from console

            if (int.TryParse(line, out value) && value <= 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Input is not a positive integer. Try again");
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Value=" + value);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. Part of this helps. I'm getting more and more lost now reading through these examples.

Answer (score 1):

you should probably have a couple of variables so you can keep track of how many loops you need to do:

```
int evenNumbersEntered = 0;
int oddNumbersEntered = 0;
```

then you should create a while loop that will continue to get input from the user until one of the two counters has reached `4`

```
// Our requirement is to loop 4 times if an even integer
// is entered and 4 times if an odd integer is entered.
while (evenNumbersEntered < 4 && oddNumbersEntered < 4)
{
    // Get user input here
}
```

When getting user input, you only need to do `int.TryParse` once. It will return `true` if it succeeds, otherwise `false`. If it succeeds, then the integer parsed from the string will be stored in the variable `value`.

```
int value;
Console.Write("Please enter a positive integer: ");
string line = Console.ReadLine();
bool validInteger = int.TryParse(line, out value);
```

Now that we have some input from the user, we need to figure out what they entered and display a message or increment one of our counters.

We know that if `TryParse` failed, the user did not enter an integer, and we should display an error message.

```
if (!validInteger)
{
    // TryParse failed, which means the user entered a non-integer string
    Console.WriteLine("ERROR: {0} is not a valid integer.", line);
}
```

Otherwise if TryParse succeeded, then you should check if `value` is less than zero (or zero), and display the appropriate error message.

```
else if (value < 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine("ERROR: {0} is a negative integer.", line);
}
else if (value == 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine("ERROR: {0} is zero.", line);
}
```

Finally, if TryParse succeeded and the value was not <= 0, then you should check if the value was even or odd, and increment the appropriate counter variable for your looping.

```
else if (value % 2 == 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Thank you! {0} is an even integer.", line);
    evenNumbersEntered++;
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Thank you! {0} is an odd integer.", line);
    oddNumbersEntered ++;
}
```

When one of these two counters reaches `4`, the `while` loop will exit. At that point you may want to display some information to the user, and pause the program so they can read it.

```
// After the while loop
Console.WriteLine("You entered {0} even numbers and {1} odd numbers",
    evenNumbersEntered, oddNumbersEntered);

Console.Write("Press any key to exit...");
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: I tried to break it up to explain the logic behind each part. Since you're new to programming, it may seem like a lot to take in. Basically all the code blocks below the second one would go inside the `while` loop (where it says, `// Get user input here`), in the order that they're presented. But the important thing it to understand the logic of how to process the data, as well as how things like `while`, `TryParse`, and `if / else if / else` statements work. Good luck!

Comment: I've been studying and trying to learn for weeks. It's a bit difficult at first. I think this would work, as simple and bare bones as it is.

            int value = 0;
            Console.WriteLine("Enter a number:");
            string line = Console.ReadLine();
            if (value == 0)
            Console.Write("Enter a positive number");
            Console.WriteLine();

Comment: @Dan That code doesn't parse the user's input (stored in `line`) into an integer.

Comment: Thanks, I'm too lost to figure this out. I appreciate your help!

Comment: The key is to break it down into pieces, and tackle one piece at a time. There are a lot of moving parts in this one.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a similar answer which breaks it down in terms of how to analyze the problem and what each step does.

> "What I'm looking to do is have a box pop up that asks the user for an
>   integer, which works."

You've already satisfied this part with:

```
Console.Write("Please enter an integer: ");
var input = Console.ReadLine();
```

-

> "After that, if the integer is negative it should say "enter a positive
>   number". Then if it's a 0, it should say "enter a non-zero number"."

For this part, we need to do a few things:

1. Check if the user actually entered an integer
2. Check if the input is negative
3. Check if the input is zero

To do this, we'll use `int.TryParse()`. This method takes a `string` to parse, and an `out` integer parameter which will contain the integer parsed from the string (an `out` parameter is one that the method guarantees will be set to some value when it returns).

`int.TryParse()` returns `true` if it was able to successfully convert the string to an integer, otherwise it returns `false`. So really, we're getting two things back from this method:

1. `true` or `false` return value (which answers the question:" Was the string an integer?")
2. the `out` parameter, which will contain the integer (if the parse succeeded)

We create two variables to capture the output of `int.TryParse`:

1. A `boolean` to capture the return value
2. An `integer` to capture the int parsed from the string

The code looks like:

```
int value;
bool success = int.TryParse(input, out value);
```

So to answer the first question, "did the user enter an integer", we examine the value of `success`, which contains the return value from `int.TryParse`:

```
if (success == false)
{
    Console.WriteLine("The value entered is not a valid integer");
}
```

To answer the second question, "is the integer negative", we examine the value of 'value'

```
else if (value < 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine("The value entered is negative");
}
```

To answer the third question, "is the integer zero", we again examine the value of 'value'

```
else if (value == 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine("The value entered is zero");
}
```

-

> "Lastly, it should loop four times if it's an even number, and it
>   should loop four times if it's an odd number."

Now it's getting trickier. When the user does enter a valid integer, we need to determine if it was odd or even. And in either case, it sounds like we will only let them enter 4 of one type. This will require a loop construct, where we execute our code over and over again until the user has either entered 4 even numbers or 4 odd numbers.

A loop construct always has a condition that it checks on each iteration to determine if it should continue looping or quit. Since our condition is: "the user has either entered 4 even numbers or 4 odd numbers", we will need to create a couple of variables to track these values. The variables will be checked on each iteration of the loop, and will be updated with new values inside the loop (when the user enters an even or odd integer).

Creating the variables is easy, just a couple of `int`s to track how many odd and even numbers have been entered:

```
int oddNumbersEntered = 0;
int evenNumbersEntered = 0;
```

Adding them as a condition to the loop isn't too hard, either. Since we want to stop looping when one of the two reaches 4, we will write something that says, 'while oddNumbersEntered is less than 4 and evenNumbersEntered is less than 4, keep getting input from the user':

```
// As soon as one of these variables equals '4', the loop will quit
while (oddNumbersEntered < 4 && evenNumbersEntered < 4)
{
    // Get user input (this is the code above)
}
```

But we also need to update those variables with new values when the user enters and even or odd number, or the loop will go on forever.

How do we know if a number is even or odd? The simplest way is to divide it by 2 and see if there is any remainder. If the remainder is 0, then it's an even number, otherwise it's odd.

To check the remainder of a division operation, we use the modulus operator (`%`), which is like a division only it returns the remainder. For example, `10 % 3 = 1` because 3 goes into 10 three times, with a remainder of 1.

```
while (oddNumbersEntered < 4 && evenNumbersEntered < 4)
{
    // Get user input (this is the code above)

    if (value % 2 == 0)
    {
        evenNumbersEntered++; // This increments our even number counter by one
    }
    else 
    {
        oddNumbersEntered++; // This increments our odd number counter by one
    }
}
```

So that should get us a working program, but since a Console application will quit when the processing is done, and we want the user to see some results, we'll add a bit of code at the end that displays the results to the user and then prompts them to press a key when they're done reading it.

Lets show them how many odd and even numbers they entered:

```
Console.WriteLine("All done! You entered {0} even and {1} odd numbers", 
    evenNumbersEntered, oddNumbersEntered);
```

And now we'll wait for them to press a key before we quit:

```
Console.Write("Press any key to exit...");
Console.ReadKey();
```

This part goes at the end of the while loop.

### Putting it all together

When we put all the code together, we have something that looks like:

```
int oddNumbersEntered = 0;
int evenNumbersEntered = 0;

// As soon as one of these variables equals '4', the loop will quit
while (oddNumbersEntered < 4 && evenNumbersEntered < 4)
{
    Console.Write("Please enter an integer: ");
    var input = Console.ReadLine();

    int value;
    bool success = int.TryParse(input, out value);

    if (success == false)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The value entered is not a valid integer");
    }
    else if (value < 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The value entered is negative");
    }
    else if (value == 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The value entered is zero");
    }
    else if (value % 2 == 0)
    {
        evenNumbersEntered++; // This increments our even number counter by one
    }
    else
    {
        oddNumbersEntered++; // This increments our odd number counter by one
    }
}

Console.WriteLine("All done! You entered {0} even and {1} odd numbers",
    evenNumbersEntered, oddNumbersEntered);

Console.Write("Press any key to exit...");
Console.ReadKey();
```